# What does the term "expected leaf node" in this exercise from Sutton-Barto mean?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, markov-decision-process, sutton-barto

What does the term "expected leaf node" in the Exercise below from Sutton-Barto mean?

[image]

Comment: Since the state value of the root is an expectation w.r.t. a policy, thus it expects leaf nodes as all its possible action values explicitly without respect to the said policy as you already understood. Do you still have questions, if not, you can close or remove this one.